# Differences between non-registered, TFSA, and RRSP accounts for short-term investments

Tags: stocks, investing, canada

I am new to stocks and I am using an application that's called Wealthsimple. The application shows different account types (non-registered, TFSA, and RRSP) but I don't understand really what are the differences.

I read online that the differences are related to taxation (like here: [Investments beyond RRSP and TFSA, in non-registered accounts?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/43834/investments-beyond-rrsp-and-tfsa-in-non-registered-accounts)) but still, it's not clear for me. I am living in Canada and I am new to the taxation system as I used to live in a country that has no taxation system.

My goal is to buy stocks and sell them (short-term trading). So, Which account type should I use?
Can someone please give an example of the differences?

**Edit**:

Can I use the non-registered account to trade and withdraw my money when I want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asset Allocation between TFSA vs RRSP](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/89591/asset-allocation-between-tfsa-vs-rrsp)

Comment: Apart from the linked question - do you intend to live permanently in Canada, or until retirement, or just a few years, or what? This will impact how significant the tax advantages of these programs would be.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon No I don't think so, but probably I'll be coming here and I almost got the Canadian passport. Also, it's not clear for me the answer there + it doesn't mention the non-registered account. Finally, what is the TFSA account annual limit (`Annual limit: ~$5.5k / year`)?

Comment: Every year of tax residency in Canada would make you eligible for an extra 5.5k / year to be contributed to your TFSA (may increase with inflation). If you won't be a tax resident in Canada, is there somewhere that your investments *will* be taxed? This is a really long discussion and needs to start with an understanding for yourself of where your life will be at least over the next few years.

Comment: There are many online explanations of TFSAs and RRSPs. Here is one I found written by ...Oh! Wealthsimple! Please read and tell us what you don't understand.

Comment: Thanks! @Grade'Eh'Bacon